# Scrolling element into view using javascrpit in RSelenium

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rselenium

I have following page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)

I want to scroll until **Milestones** heading so that it is visible in browser,

My code,

```
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))

remDr <- driver[["client"]]

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)'
remDr$navigate(url)
```

I know that,

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "html")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key="end"))
```

and

```
remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

gets me to the end of page.

Answer (score 0):

We can scroll using java script to get the element (**Milestone**) into view by,

```
#navigate to webpage
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)'
remDr$navigate(url)
```

Identify the element,

```
ele = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'//*[@id="Milestones"]')
#scroll into view
remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", list(ele))
```

[image]

Additional info,

To scroll to the middle of the page we can use,

```
remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight/2);")
```